# OAI-PMH 2.0 library in Java

Tags: java, oai

Does anyone have any experience with some open-source [OAI-PMH 2.0](http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/openarchivesprotocol.html) library for Java?

[This one](http://code.google.com/p/joailib/) could be an option but I am put off a little by the **0.1** version counter.

I 've also found [this page on the OAI-PMH site](http://www.openarchives.org/pmh/tools/tools.php) that lists a number of tools and libraries but I don't know how they stack up against each other.

Answer (score 2):

I am using [OCLC's OAIHarvester2](http://www.oclc.org/research/activities/oaiharvester2.html) . This library is from 2006, but it does all and well for me, is Open Source and has a nice license.

It's also available on Maven's central repositories: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.dspace/oclc-harvester2

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to check [XOAI](https://github.com/lyncode/xoai), which is available on Maven's central repositories.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I ended up rolling my own implementation. In retrospect OAI-PMH is not so complicated and the protocol is very clearly documented with zero fluff.

Comment: Cool! Do you provide your implementation as open source?

Comment: @Abdull It was done for a contract and open-sourcing it is not high in the client's priorities as far as I can tell.